# Бэкап базы, сделать дамп сразу на комп

Tags: mysql, linux, база-данных, bash, резервное-копирование

Такой вопос эсть большая база больше 100гб, есть возможность делать дамп и сохранть его не на машину, а локально себе на комп? И потом также заливать с компа сразу в бд? Ос linux mint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на сервере

```
mysqldump .... | gzip | nc -l 9000
```

на клиенте

```
nc server.address 9000 > dump.sql.gz
```